# CodeIgniter email to multiple people with unsubscribe link giving errors/

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, email, foreach

I want to an send email newsletter to some people,whose status is active in database,and I am done, but I also want to send an unsubscribe link with each email, I have also done it, but I am getting something wrong in the foreach loop, because each time when loop runs, it send one extra (i+1) unsubscribe link to the the user with the email. I attaching the code.

This is my view form

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="<?= base_url()?>email/send_newsletter">
<div class="box-body">
     <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Select Multiple Lists</label>
                    <select class="form-control select2" name="lists" data-placeholder="   Select List(s)">
                      <?php foreach ($lists as $list_name){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $list_name['list_id'];?>"><?php echo $list_name['list_name'];?></option>
                    <?php }?>
                    </select>
                  </div>              
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Subject</label>
                      <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter Subject">
                    </div>
                  <script src="<?= base_url()?>assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Message</label>
                      <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="editor1" cols="10" rows="5"></textarea>
                <script>

                    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
                </script>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                      <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">

                      <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="box-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This my controller method

```
public function send_newsletter()
{
     $lists = $this->input->post('lists');
     $subject = $this->input->post('subject');
     $message = $this->input->post('message');

     $join_str1 = "subscribers.subscriber_list_id=lists.list_id";

     $subscribers =  
     $this->global_model
     ->join_2table('subscribers','lists', $join_str1,['subscriber_list_id'=>$lists,'subscriber_status'=>'Active']); 



    foreach($subscribers as $row) {

        $email_lists = $row['subscriber_email'];
        $random_key = $row['random_key'];   
        $message.=
        "<a href=\"http://xyz.in/abc/unsubscribe/unsubscribe_me/{$random_key}\">Unsubscribe Here</a>";

        $from_email = 'support@xyz.com';
        $this->email->from($from_email, 'CRM'); 
        $this->email->to($email_lists);
        $this->email->subject($subject); 
        $this->email->message($message); 
        $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
        $sendmail = $this->email->send();

    }                 
        //Send mail 
        if($sendmail) 
        {
            echo "Email sent";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "email failed.";
        }      
}
```

Comment: Well you are appending a new link to $message in each loop iteration - so what else do you expect to happen …?

Comment: Have you tried using $this->email->clear(TRUE) explained here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#CI_Email::clear

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem, I just added both the variables, Like this

```
foreach($subscribers as $row) {

    $email_lists = $row['subscriber_email'];
    $random_key = $row['random_key'];   
    $message = $this->input->post('message').
    "<a href=\"http://eclabsindia.in/crm_alazizi/unsubscribe/unsubscribe_me/{$random_key}\">Unsubscribe Here</a>";

    $from_email = 'support@indiatestbook.com';
    $this->email->from($from_email, 'CRM ALAZIZI'); 
    $this->email->to($email_lists);
    $this->email->subject($subject); 
    $this->email->message($message); 
    $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
    $sendmail = $this->email->send();

}
```